# VBA: Add Item to Existing Key in Dictionary

Tags: vba, dictionary

I want to do something extremely simple and I still can't find the solution via Google.
I want to add an item to an existing key in a VBA dictionary.

My Code:

```
Sub mymacro()

Set DICT = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

For i = 1 To 10
    key = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "D").Value
    item = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "L").Value
    DICT.Add key, item
    If DICT.Exists(key) Then
        DICT(key).Add item    '(<-- causes runtime error 424, object required)
    End If
Next i

For Each i In DICT.Items: Debug.Print i: Next

End Sub
```

This code however is giving me a Runtime Error 424, 'Object required'
Any help is appreciated

Comment: You can't natively store multiple items per key, you would need the item to be an array, collection or dictionary and store each item as an element of that.

Comment: When you say add, do you meant replace the current value? Or, are you looking to update a collection?

Comment: @RyanWildry I'd like to add it so to have 2 or more items referencing 1 key

Comment: [Here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/) is a very good article how to work with dictionaries. Ansd why would you want to have the same value twiche in a dictionary. May you want to do something like _19.2 - Example 2 – Dealing with Multiple Values(https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/)_

Comment: This 'DICT(key).Add item' is incorrect code BUT because 'Item' is the default method for scripting dictionaries it is being interpreted as 'DICT.Item(Key).add' which Implies that 'DICT.Item(Key)' is returning a Dictionary and you then apply method 'Add' to the returned dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store `Collection` objects in the `Dictionary's` values.  This allows the storage of multiple values per key.  Something like:

```
Option Explicit

Sub mymacro()

Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

Dim i As Long
Dim ColumnDKey As Variant
Dim ColumnLValue As Variant
Dim ColumnLValues As Collection

For i = 1 To 10
    ColumnDKey = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "D").Value
    ColumnLValue = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "L").Value
    If Not dict.Exists(ColumnDKey) Then
        dict.Add ColumnDKey, New Collection
    End If

    Set ColumnLValues = dict.Item(ColumnDKey)
    ColumnLValues.Add ColumnLValue
Next i

For Each ColumnDKey In dict.Keys
    Set ColumnLValues = dict.Item(ColumnDKey)
    
    For Each ColumnLValue In ColumnLValues
        Debug.Print ColumnLValue
    Next
Next

End Sub
```